# How can I join only a certain range of rows in a MYSQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

I currently have a MYSQL query that is using a mathematical formula to determine the similarity of all rows in the table to a given row in that table. The query works perfectly, but now I am trying to figure out how I can only join a range of rows in percentages of total rows of the table and I am stumped.

My query is as follows,

```
SELECT t2.*, ABS(t1.v1-t2.v1)+ABS(t1.v2-t2.v2)+ABS(t1.v3-t2.v3) AS diff
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=1) AS t1
JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY diff;
```

I simply want to count the number of rows using the MYSQL count function and then only join say 10% of the rows. Each row is identified by ID, incrementing by 1, so if there is 100 rows, I only want to join row id 1-10. If the rows increase to 200, I will then want to join only 1-20.

Any help would be great!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know if this works in MySql but on MS SQL Server I would join a Select Statement instead of a full table. In the Select you could filter what you want or simply use TOP statement for only some rows...

Comment: I was trying that, but it was throwing syntax errors for some reason

Comment: You can't JOIN a range of rows, but you can `LIMIT` the result to a fixed number of results returned.